# java.lang.illegalArgumentException: Image==null?

Tags: java, image-processing, illegalargumentexception

im planning to write a java program that read the image and saves it. seems like i have struck with this issue. please help. here is my code.

```
public class test{
public static void main(String[] args){
try{
URL testurl=new URL("www.google.co.in");
img=ImageIO.read(testurl.openStream());
ImageIO.write(img,"png",new File("c:\\out.jpg"));
}
catch(IOException e){}
}
```

i also tried this with a localhost url but it didnt work. please help me. also i wish to save the image in the same name that is found in the webpage. any suggestion on how can i do that ?

Comment: `www.google.co.in` does not resolve to an image.  Did you actually look at the returned values?

Comment: thank u. i learnt that i need to give the url of the page. i tried giving the url of the webpage that contains the image.

Answer (score 4):

```
URL imageUrl = new URL("http://host.com/image.jpg");
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageUrl);

File outputFile = new File("myImage.jpg");
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputFile);
```

I'm assuming the URL you used is just a placeholder, considering it's not an image.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot automatically create an image out of an HTML file. The only way this is possible is if you render the HTML first, or if you start with an image file

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the URL you have specified. It must be able to be read as an image. As [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.InputStream)) say:

> If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting stream, null is returned.

So, if you specify a link like the following:

```
URL testurl = new URL("http://www.dotahut.com/img/icons/spells/442.png");
```

it will work.